# Fomat number series in R

Tags: r

I have a number series like below. I need the negative numbers (numbers below 0) to be zero and other numbers to be rounded to two digits.

Can somebody help me to do this in R?

Output:

```
21.31  22.0  0   8.71 -25.27   1.63  0  144.23 0 0  21.9558290  57.2186577 214.2688719  57.9806240   0 0  21.7744036  50.7217715  0 131.4853834
```

Thanks in advance.

```
pred_cty1
              1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
     21.3147237  22.0741859  -1.5040034   8.7155408 -25.2777258   1.6331518  -1.5303588 
              8           9          10          11          12          13          14 
    144.2318083 -13.1278888 -19.6253222  21.9558290  57.2186577 214.2688719  57.9806240 
             15          16          17          18          19          20 
     -7.7710546 -35.6169525  21.7744036  50.7217715  -0.4616455 131.4853834 
    > str(pred_cty1)
     Named num [1:20] 21.31 22.07 -1.5 8.72 -25.28 ...
     - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are very basic r functions and methodologies, so I'd recommend researching the concept of [subsetting](https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) and checking out `?round`. FYI, `pred_cty1` is a vector type object. 'Series' doesn't really help answer your question because there a bunch of data types that can store them.

After reading up on subsetting and `round` check out this simple solution:

```
pred_cty1 <- round(pred_cty1, digits = 2)
pred_cty1[pred_cty1 < 0] <- 0
```